# terminalide install issue -- "this tool is deprecated"

Tags: android, deprecated, terminal-ide

I've tried several times to install the terminalide app on my lenovo A7600-F tablet running Android 4.2.2.  I follow the [instructions](http://terminal-ide.googlecode.com/files/Terminal_IDE_Help.pdf) exactly, but always get the same results.  When I get to Tutorial 5, ./builder.sh produces "THIS TOOL IS DEPRECATED".  When I then enter ./install.sh, it returns a line saying "this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL".  Everything goes downhill from there, and I end up unable to compile java.

I had the same results trying to install to my phone, so I suspect I am at fault here.  I just haven't been able to find the issue.

Comment: This is the end of what I get when I type ./builder.sh

Now convert to dex format
processing MainActivity.class...
processing R$attr.class...
processing R$layout.class...
processing R$string.class...
processing R.class...
processing archive ../../libs/demolib.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
processing org/library/libfunc.class...

THIS TOOL IS DEPRECATED. See --help for more information.

Packaging demo_android.apk
./build/resources.res:
=> res/layout/main.xml
=> AndroidManifest.xml
=> resources.arsc
./build/demo_android.dex => classes.dex
Sign finished..!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can ignore the "deprecated" message. The security exception can be fixed by adding `--user 0` to the `am` command in `install.sh` and `run.sh`.